# send code segment from vim to shell for temporary testing (bash)

Tags: shell, vim

Having this typed in VIM, would it be possible to send it to shell,
as if it were typed there, so as a result I would have that function defined
in shell, and I would run it by calling it there?

```
# declare helper functions
function gen_credentials {
    cat > .credentials <<-EOM
    password: my_secret_password
    user: my_pretty_name
    db: script_db5
    dbprefix: son_45678
    live_site: sonikete3.com
    sqlfile: test-import.sql
    log_path: $(pwd)
    tmp_path: $(pwd)
EOM
}
```

The code snippet above, is a small segment of a whole file, so I would like to send piece of code as visual selection to shell, instead of passing whole script via `%` substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the lines.
2. Type `:` to enter command-line mode, the visual range is inserted automatically for you: `:'<,'>`.
3. Type `:'<,'>w !sh` and press enter.

See `:help :w_c`.

You can replace `sh` with whatever interpreter you need.

Comment: What I was missing, was that `w` part.

Answer (score 0):

The command is

```
:! ./%
```

Now, breaking it down, `:!` tells vim that you want it to pass the rest of the command to the shell.  `%` is the symbol to reference the current file.

Note that this only works if you have saved the file.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question, I know I can run whole script like that, but having that sample function code as a small segment of a much bigger file, instead of `%`, is there a way to send visual selection in the same way to shell?